# Loop through multiple HTML elements with the same ID and build objects with their data

Tags: javascript

```js
    var serviceGroupName = document.querySelectorAll('packageGroupName').value;
    var sourceType = document.getElementById("multiple-checkboxes");
    
    if (serviceGroupName !== '')
    {
         var serviceArray = [];
         for (i = 0; i < sourceType.selectedOptions.length; i++) 
         {
            serviceArray.push(parseInt(sourceType.selectedOptions[i].value));
         }
          var groupName = {};
          groupName[serviceGroupName] = serviceArray;
          ungroupedServiceArray = [];
            
    }

document.getElementById('addGroup').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('addService');

function duplicate()
{
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "addService1" + ++i; 
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="addService">
   <p><b>Service Group Name: </b></p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="packageGroupName" id="packageGroupName" minlength= 1 placeholder=" Group Name" >
    </div>
                
    <p><b>Add Services</b></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="multiple-checkboxes" multiple="multiple" class='packageGroupName'>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"></label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="duplicate()" id="addGroup">Add </button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to loop through an undefined number of HTML elements all with the same id. The reason being, every time the user clicks a button on the form, it creates a new text field and drop down, identical to the original.

I am looking to grab a string value from a text box and multiple values from a multiselect list and associate them where the string value is the key, and the multiple values from the drop down list are the values.

Here is the javascript code I have thus far:
This is grabbing the data from the text field and the multiselect list

```
var serviceGroupName = document.querySelectorAll('packageGroupName').value;
var sourceType = document.getElementById("multiple-checkboxes");

if (serviceGroupName !== '')
{
     var serviceArray = [];
     for (i = 0; i < sourceType.selectedOptions.length; i++) 
     {

         serviceArray.push(parseInt(sourceType.selectedOptions[i].value));
     }
      var groupName = {};
      groupName[serviceGroupName] = serviceArray;
      ungroupedServiceArray = [];
}
```

This is how I'd like the final output to look. Basically, however many times the user creates a new textbox and muliselect list it will create this output:

```
 "Textbox value": [  
     multiselect_values,
     multiselect_values,
     multiselect_values,
     multiselect_values
 ]
"Textbox value2":[
     multiselect_values2,
     multiselect_values2,
     multiselect_values2
 ]
```

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document, use classes instead.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same id is confusing and don’t usually work correctly, consider changing the ids to class instead.

Comment: How would you do it then Teemu?

Comment: So how would you build an undefined number of text boxes/drop downs off a button click with unique class names?

Comment: You don't use unique classes. You use common class

Comment: Okay, but that still leaves me at my original question

Comment: Provide a runnable [mcve]. Click on `<>` in question editor to make it run here in the page

Comment: Okay I have provided a minimal runnable example of what I have so far

Comment: where is your code failing exactly? 'This is grabbing the data from the text field ' - is this grabbing the data from a single data box, when do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

As others put it, you need to use a class name instead of using just an id. Instead of `<div id="addService">"` use `<div id="addService" class="service">`.

Then in your code you would do something like this:

```
var servicelist = document.querySelectorAll('.service')

for(var i=0; i<servicelist.length; i++){
    var serviceGroupName = servicelist[i].querySelector('input.packageGroupName').value;
    var sourceType = document.querySelector("select.packageGroupName");
    ..... the rest of your code
}
```